# CSS: navigation element to jump on the top of the page on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a web page and menu made with  element at the bottom of it (inside some DIVs):

```
.nav {
position: relative;
margin: 2px 0;}}
```

On smaller screens Id'd like to move menu to the top of the page.
I've added to CSS:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.nav {
    position:fixed, top:0px; 
    left:0px;
    min-height: 40px;
}
```

and tried different settings for the position tag (top, absolute, ...) to no avail.
Please help.

Comment: Any example of the non working solution ? use jsfiddle

Comment: (http://www.mihamazzini.com/EN/default.html) Try to resize the window.

Comment: Please add some relevant code

Comment: This is CSS code for NAV, computer screen: 
`.nav {
 position: relative;
 margin: 2px 0;
}`
and this is code for small screens:
`@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.nav {
 position: top;
`

Comment: Please add it to your question and not in the comments. And When I add `position:fixed`, `top:0px;` and `left:0px;` it works

Comment: I did. It doesn't work for me or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.nav {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px; 
  left:0px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

instead of:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .nav {
  position:fixed, top:0px; 
  left:0px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

You always end a css line with a `;` and than you can enter the following line. You don't end a line with a `,` like you did after `position:fixed;`

and remove the second `}` in your first rule;

```
.nav {
 position: relative;
 margin: 2px 0;
} /*one } and not two*/
```

I also have a small tip. I don't know what browser you are using but user the webconsole (F12 for the most browser). If you made a mistake it will be visible there.

Comment: No problem. I hope it will help you